# Does it make sense to write data passed between functions to memory for development in python?

Tags: python-3.x, testing

I'm still learning as I go, so forgive me if this is an obvious question. I'm trying to make development and testing easier for my scripts. The goal is to be able to more easily isolate functional groups such as calls to APIs. Would writing to memory allow me to store data between runs of my script in the same session?

So execute group ABCDE -> store the output in memory -> comment out/disable ABC -> continue developing DE referrencing the memory location until end of session.

If there is a standard/better way to do this please let me know.

Comment: what do you mean by "write to memory"??

Comment: Im basically trying to find a fast temporary holding location that will persist between runs that isn't writing to the drive. I think it's a thing to write to memory, but I might be wrong. I'm just trying better isolate sections of my scripts so I don't have to run the whole thing all the time. I'm not a CS major and don't work with other programmers so I might not the right phrasing. I'm looking for a better programming pattern I think.

Comment: Should I really just be building out test environments/test as I go?